# Change JOOMLA site background according to IF condition

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have been trying to find a solution for hours... Any comment / guidance would be very much appreciated!.. Thanks...
I created an extension for listing different products by category.
what I am trying to accomplish is changing the background of the entire site according to the category that is set, for example: electronics would be blue background, fashion would be red background etc...

I have a few problems:
1. The sorting function for the categories is dynamic, (dropdown list / submit button) so the page doesn't change (only what it shows in the module changes) so I cannot use different templates for different pages,
2. I cannot use page suffix to define a new template.

A good solution would be a php statement like:
if ($categoryId == X) --> set_new_background,
but the class for the site background is set outside of the php file I am working on.
Also setting a background for the DIV will not change the sites background.

Any ideas and help would be very much appreciated!
Thank you!

Report this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to @Theodeore's answer above, it's quite complete; the only addition I would make is to just use classes at the template level instead, so you can define your colours in the css and have classes for each category.

This will be fastest (you don't need lookup tables): so just add the folloowing $catClass to body:

```
if ($option=='com_content' && $view=='category') 
    $catClass = ' cat'.JRequest::getVar('id');
```

after this, $catClass will contain something like ' cat16' which you can append to your

So you can insert the above code in your template before "

```
<body class="your classes <?php echo $catClass; ?>">
```

which will output something like:

```
<body class="your classes cat16">
```

Then in a **single** css you will have rules:

```
body.cat16 {background-image:url(../image1.jpg);}
body.cat18 {background-image:url(../image2.jpg);}
```

this will be better than having separate css files because it will be much faster to load for browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but I have very little jquery expreinece... I am trying load a new stylesheet instead...

Comment: This is _not_ jQuery, it's php: I changed my answer to insert the new code

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the long delay, I was trying to implement your solution on my site.. I encountered a problem where in my website template.php, the css class which sets the background is declared in a div which includes the header and the body, so if I set a new body class nothing changes. What I need to do is set a new class to that div, but I am unable to do this with an IF condition since the $cat veriable is not intialized yet... it is loaded only after the template.php, and $option, $view doesn't contain any relevant data... any ideas? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: wait, you wrote that a div includes the header and the body: I hope you don't mean <div><head>...</head><body... because this would be wrong (<div> can only be within <body>).  If it's the header and "main content" however, just use a css selector that includes the div, for example: body.cat18 div.header>div or whatever your markup requires.

Comment: Actually the template was generated by artisteer, the div is inside the body tag but the background color is set in that div id and not in the body tag, as you can see I am very new to php and css :) your solution works, but for some reason if I set the <body class="someclass"> in the temlate.php it will not override it if I set a <body class="cat18"> in the component code, because the body from the template.php is loaded first, I will create a new question for this case... Thank you very much for you help, I very much appreciate it! and you tought me so much... thanks!

Comment: You cannot set the body class in a component. But you can access the content id in the template (when you are in com_content, if view=article the "id" parameter will be that of an article, if you are in view=category the "id" will be that of a category; so in the latter case you just output JRequest::getVar('id'); in the former you can use the var catid (if it's set) else you need to look it up with a query (select catid from #__content where id =...)

Comment: Thank you! the catId is not set... I found a simple solution to implement in my component code:
app =& JFactory::getApplication();
if ($category_id == 1)
$app->setTemplate("template2");  
else
....
this simply sets a new template according to the category_id of my products, I know this is not memory efficient and the loading time is longer and the worst part is that I need to create a new template for each category... but this does the trick...
what do you think?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to your problem

1)You can use template overrides for each category, loading different templates in your component

2)You can load different css styles

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
If ($cat==1){
 $document->addStyleSheet("/mybluetheme.css");
}
else
{
 $document->addStyleSheet("/myredtheme.css");
}
```

3)You can add specific classes to the body of your document using a custom plugin
http://www.rockettheme.com/magazine/jan-2012/1342-creating-a-simple-macro-replacement-plug-in

4)Least but not last you can echo a hidden div in your body specifying the color

```
<?php 
if($category==1){
$color="#ffffee";
}
else{
$color="#eeeeee";
}
echo "<div class='hiddencolor' style='display:none'>".$color."</div>";
?>
```

Then use some jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        var mycolor = $(".hiddencolor").text();
        alert(mycolor);
        // change the body background css
        $("body").css("background", mycolor);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zWzvd/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method of editing the template code. Just have to make it dynamic.
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2271520

or

you can save the category's color in a table. Query it when the page loads and use it to color the site's background if a value is returned. Basically putting the code in the template.